# No ROS_WORKSPACE set

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have upgraded from Electric to Fuerte on Ubuntu 11.10.  Every time I type roscd, I get  No ROS_WORKSPACE set.

This is part of my bashrc:

```
#source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash 
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}
#source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
#source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
source  ~/setup.sh
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash

source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
```

I  appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45248/no-ros_workspace-set/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-07**:
what do you get when you type "echo $ROS_WORKSPACE"

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2012-10-07**:
when I type echo $ROS_WORKSPACE, I don't get anything

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-10-07**:
As mentioned below, try adding the ros workspace in bashrc or setup.sh. Try creating a new workspace or overlay following the tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my opinion you would benefit from cleaning up your .bashrc, ideally there should only be one line in it regarding ROS workspaces, which could be:

```
$ source ~/ros_workspace/setup.sh
```

This setup.sh in ~/ros_workspace could best be created using rosws or rosinstall, and it would set the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH for you.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-08**:
[Relevant link](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays)

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-10-09**:
Except some people are still getting used to the idea of workspaces, remember how long it took me to drink the kool-aid...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS Fuerte, calling `roscd` without any arguments switches the current directory to the path defined in `$ROS_WORKSPACE`.

See here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem#Special_cases_for_roscd

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1